# Programmatically export employees' data with Google Takeout

Tags: google-takeout

I'm working in programming at a company that wants to export all Google data from a former employee during off-boarding.

Right now the process is the super admin goes resets the former employee's password and performs a Google Takeout extraction manually, which is tedious and costly to do at a large scale.

I had trouble finding decent solutions, in fact I believe no such API exists for Takeout. Are there any workarounds or software that you'd suggest?